# How to get a user from CDC tables in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, cdc

I wonder if anyone had ever stumbled upon finding a user which made a data change (update) in the table that has activated CDC (Change Data Capture).

For example, table "User" has its corresponding table, in which info about changes is stored, called "User_CT" and it has a column called **__$start_lsn** which can be used in a function sys.fn_cdc_map_lsn_to_time to get the time of that transaction. Can you, somehow, find which user executed that transaction?

I really hope that there is an answer to that question.

Comment: Aside: In many cases the database user isn't well correlated with a person, e.g. it is common for a website to use one set of credentials to access a database regardless of the number of website users and whether or not they are "guests" or have logged in to website accounts.

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34079/change-data-capture-how-to-know-who-made-the-change

Comment: Thank you @RazvanSocol!!! Considering your helpful comment, do you know where to find the answer for the same question but for PostgreSQL RDBMS?

Comment: @DorijanGrgic: I am not familiar with PostgreSQL, sorry.

Comment: @RazvanSocol Nevermind, thank you once again :)